# Android Service is recreated after destroying activity

Tags: android, sockets, service, background-process

First of all I'm creating app that must be working in the background (even if user killed application). I have bluetooth server (raspberry pi) and my app should act like a client to that server. When connection is established I need to keep it alive and disconnect only if user is too far prom server or server sends specific disconnection command. So I simply found BluetoothChatExample and put all the code from activity to service (because I need to communicate even if user kills application and my service should be independent from my main activity).

Here's some code snippets from my service

```
public class BluetoothCommunicationService extends Service {
    public BluetoothCommunicationService() {

    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
       super.onCreate();

   //....
   //....
   //....
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
       if(intent.getAction.equals("stop") {
           stopSelf();
       }
       return START_STICKY;
    }

private class AcceptThread extends Thread {
            //....
}

private class ConnectThread extends Thread {
    //....
}

private class ConnectedThread extends Thread {
    //....
}

@Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();

}
```

}
So as you can see I started my service as `START_STICKY` but here's the problem when I'm killing the application from the "recently used apps" list I'm also killing my service (even if `onDestroy()` is not called!!!) and then again `onCreate` is called and service is starting itself from scratch. But bluetooth communication is based on sockets so they are also recreated and my connection is lost. I also tried `START_NOT_STICKY` however then my service is destroyed as soon when I close my app and it's never recreated. Is it possible to keep service alive even (and not recreate it) after user closed my app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> First of all I'm creating app that must be working in the background
>   (even if user killed application).

Not unless you are a system app you are not. Android's app model is very clear that apps cannot force themselves to run continuously, for good reason. What if a large number of apps on your phone decided to do that? Mobile devices are not desktop computers. They have batteries and can't achieve reasonable battery life with processes continuously spinning in the background. To get reasonable battery life, Android depends on being able to put the CPU to sleep when nothing is going on.

Moreover, if a user swipes away your activity, the app will be put in an inactive state. That means it cannot receive broadcasts (that includes alarm manager wakeups), and can only be re-started by the user starting your activity from the launcher, another app starting one of your activities, or another app starting a service within the app. This is also true for newly installed apps: they can't run until you explicitly use them.

For non-system apps, the best you can do is use [`startForeground()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#startForeground(int,%20android.app.Notification)) + `START_STICKY`. This is the strongest indicator to Android that your service is important and should not be killed.

System apps can declare themselves persistent in their manifest, and their process will never be killed. Unless you are building the Android dist and flashing it yourself though this isn't going to be an option.

Answer (score 2):

You can't guarantee that the service will not be killed. It can and will terminate at some point, closing all apps will destroy your service. The only benefit you get from `START_STICKY` is that it will try to re-start the service later on.

Answer (score 1):

This is as designed.  When you swipe away an app in recent apps, its kills the entire application.  This includes any background services.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible to keep your service alive. You should add to your manifest:

```
<service android:name=".BluetoothCommunicationService"
            android:process=":nameNewProcessThatYourServiceWillUseHere"/>
```

Now your service will work on independent process than your initial app process.

Comment: Running the service in a different process has no effect on Android's decision whether to shut down the service or kill of the process.

Comment: Yes, but if you kill the process of your app and you want to keep your service running you have to make separate process for it. Killing process of the app and only app won't affect service's process, as far as I understand it they work independently and that is what David was asking about.

Comment: If he was only talking about the user manually killing the process, the answer would be "don't do that".

Answer (score 0):

Your service should restart after some time if it had been previously started, returned START_STICKY or START_REDELIVER_INTENT and declared in the manifest. Android will decide that time and it will log it in the monitor console. It says something like:

```
Scheduling restart of crashed service com.company.app/MyService in 1000ms
```

Oh, if you want to see this message in Android Studio, make sure you set the Android Monitor logcat to Verbose and No Filters. Filtering by your service's class name will also help, like so:

[image: Android Studio logcat]

And again, first make sure that your service is running. If you don't declare it in the manifest, it won't start.

Comment: "Your service should restart"- exactly, it should, and normally will, but Android doesn't guarantee it, and this doesn't help keep it running persistently.

Comment: Yea well you don't really have any other chance, so it is the best you can do to keep something running when your app is closed.

Comment: It's actually not the best you can do. See my post, and reference the Android docs.

Comment: I would say it is the best you can do in this case, since it is a Bluetooth service, and you probably don't want UI updates, which is what foreground services are meant for. Such as music playing, VOIP calls or file downloading. Foreground services require posting notifications via a Notification object, and I wouldn't want that to talk to a Raspberry Pi server (or any server). But of course, it is David who should decide that.